# PHP Select options in CCK field

Tags: entities

I want to create a CCK field with options determined by PHP. On the content admin page,  in the `Allowed Values PHP code` the example it gave was

`return array(
  value_1 => label_1,
  value_2 => label_2
  ...
);`

However, I want one of the options to be the user's name, so I used something like:

```
global $user;
$name=$user=>$name;
return array( 'main_guy' => 'No', $name => 'yes' );
```

For some reason, it won't accept quotes or dollar signs. If I delete the first two lines, and remove the quotes and dollar signs (`return array(main_guy => No, name => yes);`), it works ok.

Any ideas?
 That would be the same as the standard, non-dynamic list options.

Comment: For a start, the PHP is wrong. Change your second line to `$name = $user->name;`

Comment: No worries, I'll move my comment into an answer so this one can be closed off :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP is incorrect :(

The second line should read `$name = $user->name;`.